# How do I install the any package from privates PPA without needing Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: apt

I have Ubuntu 13.04, and I am able to install [IntelliJ CE](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/free_java_ide.html) via the Ubuntu software center. When I do so I see it as an installed debian package:

```
zippy1981@scala-dev:~$ dpkg --get-selections |grep intellij
intellij-idea-ce                install
```

The repository for it seems to be `https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/intellij-idea-ce/ubuntu/`:

```
maya@ubuntu:~/Documents/src/scala$ apt-cache policy intellij-idea-ce
intellij-idea-ce:
  Installed: 12.1-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 12.1-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 12.1-0ubuntu1 0
        500 https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/intellij-idea-ce/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

However, if I do `add-apt-repository https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/intellij-idea-ce/ubuntu/` and `apt-get update` that repo gives me an error and `apt-get install intellij-idea-ce` does not find the package.

Is there a way to install this without the use of the Software Center?

Comment: @Braiam I understand that. I want to script it so I can install it on another machine, without having to launch Ubuntu software center.

Comment: @Braiam the question subject and body both say "from the command line"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good Intellij installation on ubuntu 15](http://askubuntu.com/questions/649251/good-intellij-installation-on-ubuntu-15)

Comment: See my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/649920/367165)

Answer (score 3):

As of recently, you can use [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
umake ide idea
```

Comment: -1 `ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make ` isn't OPs private repository

Comment: @A.B.: Thanks for the comment to explain the downvote. He said "Is there a way to install this without the use of the Software Center?" and "I want to script it so I can install it on another machine, without having to launch Ubuntu software center. " and 'the question subject and body both say "from the command line" '.  Makes it seem as though the main point is *not* the private repo, but **not using the software center**.

Comment: @A.B. I tried the procedure above and failed at installing IntelliJ by it. (not knowing which password/username to use)

Comment: Ok, right. Removed the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

When you access the private ppa, you need username and password (just try to go there with [your browser](https://username%3apassword@private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/intellij-idea-ce/ubuntu/)), but the software center login for you, making the process flawlessly. But, apt-get doesn't know any of this, so you should change your url to login these ppa's:

```
sudo add-apt-repositories https://username:password@private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/intellij-idea-ce/ubuntu/
```

or adding manually the lines to your `sources.list`:

```
deb https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/intellij-idea-ce/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64
```

If you need help about what url you should write, consult your [suscription page](https://launchpad.net/people/+me/+archivesubscriptions) in LaunchPad

Comment: If I add a private PPA to the sources.list file, where will I place the credential information ? Your `sources.list` example does not show that ?