# How to start IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij

I have installed JDK8 from Oracle and IntelliJ using this tutorial; [Good Intellij installation on ubuntu 15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649251/good-intellij-installation-on-ubuntu-15/649266)

I am on step #4 where I am supposed to "Start IntelliJ to configure and create a desktop entry". How do I start it?

Comment: Inside the directory containing IntelliJ, there will be a `bin` folder in which you will find a `.sh` script you can run to start it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

go to the directory through the terminal where the installation files were extracted  and

```
cd bin
./idea.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the bin folder to your path variable. Your path variable can be edited with `sudo vi /etc/environment`.
As with all sudo commands, care should be taken. Think before you write and don't just copy what i wrote.

in `/etc/environment`, you should see PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:[more path locations]"
in `/etc/environment`, Add the following line after the lasth path, before the double quote that ends the variable:
`:/path/to/intelliJ/bin/folder`.
In the case of the linked guide you would have to add: `:/opt/idea-IC/bin`.

Then you have to log out (or reboot) for the changes you made to take effect. Afterwards you should be able to start intelliJ by running the command `idea.sh`

Comment: Could you please explain why it's necessary to add IntelliJ to the `PATH` environment variable? What's the adavantage or difference compared to a direct invocation?

Comment: The advantage to adding it to the path variable is that you can call it from anywhere without having to enter the full path every time. - Unless i'm mistaken?

Comment: That's correct, but considering that OP's aim is to to follow the tutorial which suggests to start the application *once* which will then set up an application starter, I don't find your approach useful enough to justify the additional complexity. Hence the down-vote.

Comment: This comment helped me, as the application starter auto setup didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the in the idea-ic extracted folder idea/bin(using cd command like **cd /idea/bin**) and then run the command:

**To run in the background:** *./idea.sh &*   (with the if you close the terminal then IntelliJ still run )

**To run without background:** *./idea.sh*   (with the if you close the terminal then IntelliJ also exit )

Answer (score 0):

for your question, I will tell you how to install IntelliJ step by step which I followed.

1. first download

   https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=linux this is for Linux version
2. Then Extract .gz file

> ```
> sudo tar -xzf {package name}.tar.gz -C /opt
> ```

*make sure to add your package name*

x: This tells tar to extract the files.

v: This option will list all of the files one by one in the archive. The “v” stands for “verbose.”

f: This option tells tar that you are going to give it a file name to work with.

3. go to the bin folder in the install directory

> `cd ./{package name}/bin`

4. install by terminal

> `./idea.sh`

5. then install it as normal software

There also other ways to install IntelliJ follow https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/installation-guide.html